# How to associate databases with a catalog in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

What is it that associates databases with the AWSDataCatalog in Athena? We have local databases we create - in our Dev account these all show up under Associated Databases for AWSDataCatalog. So when we select AWSDataCatalog in the Data Source dropdown, it populates the Database dropdown with all of these databases and we can query from them. In Prod, however, we cannot. There are no databases in the dropdown and the Data Source shows no associated databases. All of our roles and policies are identical in test and prod, so something else is causing these not to show up. Any hints as to what it is? What makes them Associated Databases?

Comment: How did the databases get populated in your Dev environment? It would have either been via AWS Glue or by running `CREATE TABLE` commands. You can do similar in your Prod environment.

Comment: The tables were created using Terraform in both environments.  (aws_glue_catalog_table resource to be precise)  Same code, by the same role, etc.

Comment: Well, if the database tables are not appearing, then it would seem that Terraform did _not_ create them in both environments. Are they appearing in the AWS Glue console?

Comment: Yes, the tables are there.  They are visible in Lake Formation.  But in Athena when we select AWSDataCatalog as the Data Source, those databases do not appear.  If we goto Data Sources in Athena and select AWSDataCatalog, there are no associated databases listed. In our dev environment, there are numerous databases.